Azure Graph API Get User and ALL Groups in one call
I would like to call Azure and get user details and their group list, in one call.
This is similar to: Microsoft Graph API with Azure AD B2C: Get all users and their group membership
The problem is that EXPAND it too erroneous to use since it only returns up to 20 results.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#expand-parameter
This is basically what I want, just without the group limitation:
v1.0/users/?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'MYNAME'$select=id,givenName$expand=memberOf($select=id)

Due to the limitation, I've had to break this into two query calls where the second gets all groups directly, after getting the result from the first call:
v1.0/users/${user.id}/memberOf/?&$select=id

Having to double the API calls is very inefficient.  This isn't really Graph, it is OData.  How can I make an actual Graph call to get the equivalent of that first OData call, but without the group limitations of EXPAND?  Surely there is an actual Graph API for this, I just can't seem to find any details on it.

You are correct, expand will limit to 20 items.
From what I know you have two options:
Simple option, make two calls by using /users/{id}/memberOf after you fetch the user. Watch out for rate limits on this multiple calls.
Complex option option is to use Delta Queries on Groups and Users combined with Change notifications to have your own local copy of the changes so that you can do whatever you want. See Change Tracking.
In this mode the change notification will tell you something has changed, then you do a delta query. There is also possibility od performing delta query every once in a while
Since you are running out of the 20 groups membership limit in expand, you have a large dataset I suppose. One of the above will work well.
